# Set value in edittext and send it to arduino after button pressed Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, arduino

i don't know how i can solve problem with integer how to send value which was set in EditText and send after button pressed from Android on Arduino.

```
'

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String DEFAULT_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "00:12:10:16:12:14";
private Context context;
    TextView value, display;
    EditText nasttemp;
    Button button;  

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final int nastaviTemp = Integer.parseInt(nasttemp.getText().toString());

        context = this;
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nasttemp);

        //////////// Button SET /////////////////// 
          Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Amarino.sendDataToArduino(context, DEFAULT_DEVICE_ADDRESS, 'o',
                         new int[] { nastaviTemp );                    
             }      
            }); 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
```

'

Answer (score 0):

First thing is u are doing wrong thing:-

```
final int nastaviTemp = Integer.parseInt(nasttemp.getText().toString());
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nasttemp);
```

right thing is

```
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nasttemp);
final int nastaviTemp = Integer.parseInt(nasttemp.getText().toString());
```

how can u get value before intialize .

Comment: This is from logcat: Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags:0   FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: No, but that is next step to set default value.

Comment: Now it is working! But when i press a button it crashed again.

Comment: I think i first need get string from EditText and then from it in to Integer but i don't know the way.

Comment: i thing the problem in ur function "new int[] { nastaviTemp " ?? cant understand what will u do ??

Comment: Send that data to Arduino i take that from example (other project).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my code and here is it for others who will face with it.

```
    TextView vrednostTemp, display;
EditText nasttemp;
Button Nastavi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vrednostTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);
    nasttemp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nasttemp);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stanjeTemp);
    Nastavi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    context = this; 

    Nastavi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int nastaviTemp = Integer.valueOf(nasttemp.getText().toString());
            display.setText("" + nastaviTemp);
            Amarino.sendDataToArduino(context,DEVICE_ADDRESS, 'o',
                   new int[] { nastaviTemp });              
            }
        });
    }
```